# define two Parameter for ObjectDataSource one from gridview and one from login user

Tags: asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource, detailsview

I have a asp GridView and a DetailView in my page.I am using asp ObjectDataSource to bind data to my DetailsView. I am calling a method from data layer to get the data.method have a parameter (UserIdSender, UserIdReceiver).I want to pass the UserIdSender parameter from selected row gridview and UserIdReceiver from Logged in parameter. i don't know How i can retrieve UserIdReceiver?

```
<SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="AdminGridView" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Name="Senderuserid" DbType="Guid"></asp:ControlParameter>
            <asp:Parameter DbType="Guid" Name="ReceiverUserId"></asp:Parameter>
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fortunately find its solution. 
just add *OnSelecting* on *objectDataSource* and in code behind for assigning UserIdReceiver:

```
e.InputParameters["ReceiverUserId"] = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

for UserIdSender just go ahead with:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa581796.aspx